# test bind event function with sinon

Tags: sinon, enzyme

I'm having trouble tracking down why a sinon spy isn't being triggered.

**actually happys:**
  1. console printed touchStartHandler
  2. touchstartSpy.callCount is 0

I used **TypeScript React jest enzyme sinon**

This is what one of my tests generally looks like:
*.ts：

```
constructior (props: ICompatibleDivProps) {
  super(props)
  this.touchStartHandler = this.touchStartHandler.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.divElement.addEventlistener('touchstart', this.touchStartHandler, { passive: true })  
}

render () {
  const { style, className} = this.props
  retutn (
    <div>
      ref={div => this.divElement = div}
      style={style}
      className={className}
      onClick={this.props.onClick}
    </div>
  )
}

touchStartHandler (e: TouchEvent) {
  console.log('touchStartHandler')
}
```

*.test.ts：

```
mport { mount } from 'enzyme'
import CompatibleDiv from './CompatibleDiv'
import { spy } from 'sinon'
test('event called is normal', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <CompatibleDiv />
  )
  const instance = wrapper.instance() as CompatibleDiv
  const touchstartSpy = spy(CompatibleDiv.prototype, 'touchStartHandler')

  const div = wrapper.find('div').getDOMNode()
  div.dispatchEvent(new Event('touchstart'))

  expect(touchstartSpy.callCount).toBe(1)
})
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you spy on `CompatibleDiv` directly and not it's instance, so ... `const touchstartSpy = spy(CompatibleDiv.prototype, 'touchStartHandler')` and you wanna do that before you render the component, so at the top of the file, before `test`

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks dude, you save my day. :)     O(∩_∩)O谢谢

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should spy on `CompatibleDiv` component directly and not it's instance, so ...

```
const touchstartSpy = spy(CompatibleDiv.prototype, 'touchStartHandler')
```

... and you wanna do that before you render the component, so at the top of the file, before `test`.